# What shape does $x+y+z+w=0$ form in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

What shape does $x+y+z+w=0$ form in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

I suspect that it's a plane in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Is my intuition correct? why?

Comment: The title is not part of the body for a reason. It's not that your question is very long. You can easily copy it *also* into the body of your question to make it all more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In that case we refer to a **[hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane)** which is a subspace whose dimension is one less than that of its ambient space.

Indeed in that case the given equation $x+y+z+w=0$ define a subspace $\subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$ with dimension $3$.

To show this rigorously we need

- to check that it  is a subspace
- to check that its dimension is $3$

Can you show these two fact?

Comment: Awesome thanks! It's a subspace because it's closed under addition and scalar multiplication and I think that the dimension is 3 because it's spanned by three independent vectors.

Comment: @Josh Exactly! Perfect explanation and can you give three spanning vectors?

Comment: I know how to show closure under addition and multiplication but am not sure how to show that the smallest spanning set consists of three independent vectors -- Is it because we have x=-y-z-w?

Comment: sure (1,1,1,-3), (-1,1,0,0), (-1,0,1,0)

Comment: @amWhy "Rigorously", I took note of it! Thanks

Comment: From x+ y+ z+ w= 0,  w= -x- y- z.  Taking x= 1, y= z= 0, w= -1 we have that (1, 0, 0, -1) is in this space.  Taking y= 1, x= z= 0, w= -1 so we have that (0, 1, 0, -1) is in this space.  Taking z= 1, x= y= 0, w= -1 so we have that (0, 0, 1, -1) is in this space.

Comment: @Josh Yes that's a fine selection. More in general from $x+y+z+w=0$ we can obtain three linearly independent vectors taking $y=r,z=s,w=t$ and then $x=-r-s-t$ then for $(r,s,t)=(1,0,0)$ we obtain $(-1,1,0,0)$, for $(r,s,t)=(0,1,0)$ we obtain $(-1,0,1,0)$, for $(r,s,t)=(0,0,1)$ we obtain $(-1,0,0,1)$.

Comment: @Josh By that method you don't need to guess them but you can find them in a rigorous way.

Comment: @user247327 Thanks for your intervention, a double check and suggestion is always useful :)